# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, oledb, sqlbulkcopy

i have followed the answer to this thread [C# import excel filesheet to sql database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961669/c-sharp-import-excel-filesheet-to-sql-database-error) and am able to import excel data into an SQL Server Database. The only problem am having is that the Import works only when am running the website locally from Development machine but after deploying the site to IIS, i get the following error when trying to import the data from excel.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server is missing the required DLL.  You can find an install only [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734).

> This download will install a set of components that can be used to
>   facilitate transfer of data between 2007 Microsoft Office System files
>   and non-Microsoft Office applications.

Comment: is a full installation of Microsoft office on the Server a prerequisite for the installation you mention?

Comment: No, this is just a `Data Connectivity Components` download.  It will install the required drivers for use to connect with Microsoft Office applications.

Comment: Or do you know of any known alternative that does not involve installing anything on the server

Answer (score 1):

Install the follwoing, find the correct verions.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255